# Dropbox API doesn't return metadata for png files

Tags: javascript, dropbox-api, dropbox-sdk-js

Dropbox API to get the metadata for doesn't return anything for .png files. It was working fine recently but doesn't work now.

Here is the API call I make:

```
this.dropbox.filesGetMetadata({
   path: file.id,
   include_media_info: true
}).then((mdata) => {
   console.log(mdata.media_info)
})
```

This prints `undefined`, when I specify ID of .png file, but for other image files like .jpeg it works fine and prints `media_info` object with all the metadata I need.

Does anybody have similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

The [`filesGetMetadata`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-js/Dropbox.html#filesGetMetadata__anchor) method gives you a [`FilesFileMetadata`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-js/global.html#FilesFileMetadata) object for which `media_info` is marked `<optional>`, so it's not guaranteed to be available for every file. You should make sure your app is able to handle where `media_info` isn't defined. If you print out `mdata` itself you should see the rest of the non-optional metadata though.

If you're suddenly seeing `media_info` not defined for exact files that were definitely getting this set before, that may be a bug/regression you can report here:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/contact

Please include a sample file that exhibits the issue, the full output with `media_info` you previously got, and the latest output without the `media_info`.

By the way, make sure you also catch any errors, like:

```
.catch(function(error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```